# I need to know how to change the explosion texure

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to make the explosion texture from a creeper change so it looks like it is a bunch of pennies...
Anyone know how to do this?
I'd really love to know how to do it myself

Comment: Have you created a resource pack? If not, look up how and do that first. The textures for explosions are in a file that should be called particles, along with all of the other particle effects.

Answer (score 2):

This can be edited by creating a resource pack. [HERE](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Creating_a_resource_pack) is a tutorial on how to do so. If you just want the explosion changed, just change that texture and leave the rest the same. It is a particle effect , so it is in the particles folder and called explosion. NOTE: This will also change all other explosion textures to the same thing. If you want pennies every time he explodes, you will have to change all of the 12-16 textures in the file.

Comment: Any explosions- creepers, TNT, fireballs, end crystals, etc- will be changed if you change the explosion texture.